# JQuery Ajax Syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an ajax request to a server using the following using the chrome console:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-MiniAddProduct',
    data: {
        "request": "ajax",
        "Quantity": "1",
        "g-recaptcha-response": "redacted",
        "responseformat": "json",
        "sku": "AQ5934",
        "pid": "AQ5934_660"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    complete: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

however I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

I'm lead to believe that the issue is due to a syntax error, I cannot locate a syntax error in the following method, could someone help me locate it?

Comment: How have you loaded in the jQuery script?

Comment: Shouldn't have to as I'm using the chrome console

Comment: Is jQuery loaded on the page you're inspecting with the console?

Comment: @Iwan.J JQuery isn't magically available in the console.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm only a beginner, I was googling the issue before I asked here and it inclined me to believe that it was due to syntax

Comment: @Iwan.J Don't worry about it-but the error did tell you exactly what was wrong. We were all beginners once, and it's okay not to know everything. Sometimes people here forget that and say dickish things, myself included.

Comment: You're better than most beginners: you actually know how to check for errors ;) But yeah, when it tells you what the error is...

Answer (score 1):

That error happens because you might not have the jquery library on your project.

You always need to add the library before your javascript file to work properly, like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/your/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't have to as I'm using the chrome console

Comment: You always need to add the jquery library, with or without chrome console.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know this. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, you can know more about jQuery here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you load the jquery library, which you can do by using (the version below can be changed):

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, from the looks of the code you provided, you aren't putting your ajax call inside a jQuery document ready function. Do the following (the first and last lines are new):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* NEW LINE */
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-MiniAddProduct',
        data: {
            "request": "ajax",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "g-recaptcha-response": "redacted",
            "responseformat": "json",
            "sku": "AQ5934",
            "pid": "AQ5934_660"
        },
        method: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        complete: function(data, status, xhr) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}); /* NEW LINE */
```

If you're testing this on localhost, then you will be getting a CORS error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-MiniAddProduct. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Perhaps you have a separate script for authenticating?